# The sum, difference and product of two constructible numbers is a constructible number.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm studying construction with straightedge and compass and I've come to the problem requiring to show that sum, difference and product of constructible numbers is constructible. To the sum is easy. But I have no idea how to show the product part.

Comment: Representation of the product requires a reference *unit length* to be designated.  Overlooking this aspect may have led to your "no idea how" circumstance.

Comment: The constructible numbers form a field.